# How do I safely fix ESLint`no-fallthrough` error for intentional switch case ommissions of break/return/throw?

Tags: javascript, typescript, switch-statement, eslint, typescript-eslint

For my application, I want to use a switch case pattern. Some cases require OR logic, which means that there are intentional fallthroughs in the code for brevity. However, ESLint doesn't like that and throws errors. I tried adding comments as per docs, but that didn't help. To reproduce, try this:

```js
switch(num) {
  case 1:
    /*
      I also have comments in my code that explain functionality to non-developers.
    */
  case 2:
    return "if one or two";
  case 3:
    return "if three only";
}
```

ESLint with default settings will throw:

```
Error: Expected a 'break' statement before 'case'.  no-fallthrough
```

**How do I inform ESLint to expect an exception specifically in this block of code?**

I understand that there are ways to design this differently, i.e. with if statements and early return pattern, which is my usual approach. However, I want this part of the system to be readable to non-developers. I expect TypeScript and Jest to keep things decent.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-fallthrough Please have a look at the official doc

Comment: Tried adding `/* eslint no-fallthrough: ["error", { "allowEmptyCase": true }] */` (above switch) and `// falls through` (next to switch statement) comments. ESLint still errors.

Comment: Can you attach your eslint config here? What do you use for the config, js or what?

Comment: `.eslintrc.json`

`
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "next",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": { "jsx": true, "modules": true },
    "ecmaVersion": 2019,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["jam3", "prettier", "react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": { "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"] },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "17.0"
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Cr3ip5M3 Here's the complete json you can use

Comment: Thank you. But I was expecting to only create an exception for ESLint for that particular block of code — the rest of the switch statements should be showing errors as usual.

Comment: Okay, I can see yo have added it as an answer, it should work as well

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The answer I came up with is based on your insight 

Answer (score 4):

I ended up taking @dream-bold's answer but applying it in the code instead of across the project:

```js
/* eslint-disable no-fallthrough */
switch (num) {
  case 1:
    // falls through
  case 2:
    return "if one or two";
  case 3:
    return "if three only";
}
/* eslint-enable no-fallthrough */
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your eslint config file,

```
...
'rules': {'no-fallthrough': ['error', {'commentPattern': 'break[\\s\\w]*omitted'}] 
...
```

and in your code:

```
switch(foo) {
    case 1:
        doSomething();
        // break omitted

    case 2:
        doSomething();
}
```

You can read more details [here](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-fallthrough#commentpattern).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/emL33JQ1

Comment: Nice. I went with `// fallthrough` as the comment, inspired by the keyword in a few languages (ex Go and Swift)